# Log streaming tab doesn't work in Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I posted this on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4727) earlier, but hoping I would get an answer here from the wider community.

In the azure portal, one can look at live logs of a Function app in the `Log Streaming` tab. I have noticed that this often doesn't work for weeks, and I am wondering if I am doing something obviously wrong. More details below:

I have a function that receives messages from a service bus. I am able to see the logs in application insights, and I can see that it's processing the requests as expected. The problem is that I don't see any logs in the "Log Streaming" tab in the portal. See image below:

[image]

The above image indicates that no lines were logged between 6:17:46 and 6:18:46. However, see the below image from application insights logs, and you can see there were clearly several requests that were processed during this time (and several log lines written).

[image]

[image]

I tried Edge browser and Chrome, and also private tab in Edge, but I see the same behavior.

Note that I end up seeing this for extended period of time, and then sometimes it resolves itself. For example, I noticed it not work for weeks in June. Then, surprisingly I saw it work for at least a week in the beginning of July. But now I noticed it is not working.
Also, I see this behavior across all the function apps that I currently have. (So it's not limited to just one app).

I am using Azure Functions v2 .net core, C#.

Comment: Looks like Brett has answered your question on the Github issue. If you've already solved this issue, could you share your solution here as well?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't solve this issue. I just stopped looking at the Log Streaming tab :(